# App crashes due to memory leak - Swift

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, swift3, xcode8

I'm developing an iOS app that displays more than 1000 images -locally stored-, After using it for some time, **app crashes due to memory leak**.

I tried Profile tool, but couldn't figure out where the issue is, I'm displaying these images in both tableView and Icarousel. scrolling through app, memory increases but doesn't seem to be released.

> Things I've already done:
>
> 1. Resizing Images(This just delayed the crash).
> 2. Clearing dictionaries and datasources- didn't make any difference-.
> 3. I tried Using "contentsOfFile" instead of "named" property when creating image- didn't make any difference also-.
> 4. Clearing the image in reusable func in the tableViewCell -nothing changed-.

**Note:** 
I'm using `AdMob`, but even when I don't use it, **memory still leaks**.

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone can assist you without guessing. How do you even know it is images causing the problem if you do not know what is leaking? For instance there could be a logic error in your code and you have Abandoned Memory. I can only recommend you do an internet search for `iOS find memory leak` and see what general tutorials are available. Also, review Apple's documentation on performing `Memory Analysis`: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/CommonMemoryProblems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH91-SW1

Comment: you mentioned you are using lots of images - Are you doing caching of the images? If not try using SDWebImage. Most of the times apps involving lots of images run into OOM errors due to not caching images properly.

Comment: Robotic Cat: Thanks, I'm not sure images are the cause of the crash, but using app with less images solves part of the issue. I tried different approaches also not related to images, but didn't change a thing. I'll try what you suggested though, Thanks.

Comment: Dhiraj Das: App should work offline that's why we needed images to be locally stored. also named caches images, but supposedly memory releases them after sometime, but apparently that didn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you're storing your images in NSArray or something like that to represent them in table view.
Try to use NSCache to store your images in RAM. It will automatically clean used memory if it'll need.